# Свойство Length массива как условие для программы

Tags: c#

Код ниже читает строки в текстовом файле и преобразовывает в массив. Это понятно. Но на этом мне нельзя останавливаться. Условие, которое надо выполнить для продолжения работы - **именно** шесть строк в файле. Как должно быть:
* шесть строк - программа продолжает работу
* меньше шести строк - программа выдаёт окно с ошибкой и завершает работу.

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(f.FullName, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")))
 {
     string str = "";
     string s = "";
     while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
           {
               str += s + "@";//делим текст при помощи собаки на строки
           }
               string[] split = str.Split('@');
               int counter = split.Length;
               if (counter == 6)                   
               {
                   //действия
               }
               else
               {
                   //выход из приложения
               }
```

В моём случае программа всегда завершает работу с ошибкой, даже если ставлю условие "меньше или равно шести". Строк в файле шесть, проверено. Не пойму, что делаю не так. Текст переведён в массив, Length - свойство массива, целое число. Подскажите, в чём ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f.FullName, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")))
{
  string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
  string[] split = str.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  int counter = split.Length;
  if (counter == 6)                   
  {
    //действия
  }
  else
  {
    //выход из приложения
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь работает :) Да, конечно, у меня был перебор с изобретением велосипеда заново

Comment: вместо StreamReader, чтения текста, и последующего деления на строки, намного проще загрузить строки с помощью метода System.IO.File.ReadAllLines

Comment: @Stack - Не препятствовать! Полыхаев :)

Comment: @Igor _"Не препятствовать! :)"_ -- чему?)

Comment: @Stack использованию System.IO.File.ReadAllLines. В смысле: нет возражений.

Answer (score 3):

Как у вас всё сложно!
Это же C#, тут не обязательно мучиться.

Делайте так:

```
var lines = File.GetLines(f.FullName, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
var first6lines = lines.Take(6).ToList();
if (first6lines.Count < 6)
{
    // ... то выдать сообщение об ошибке и свалить
}
// а дальше проходитесь циклом по строкам и делайте с ними, что хотите
```

Comment: Не умею я не мучиться :D Неделю, как взялся за этот чудо-язык - и никак не привыкну к тому, что здесь на все случаи жизни есть методы, свойства, типы данных и всё, чего душа пожелает. С места в карьер так не прыгают, конечно, но задание было дано - а я согласился. Поэтому и начал сюда обращаться, тяжело с нуля.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"c:\log.txt").Select((line, index) => {
    if (index > 6)  // создать исключение, если строк больше чем надо
       throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(); 
    // здесь можно парсить строку, и создать объект с дополнительными данными
    return new { Index = index, Text = line, Ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks };
});

// прочесть все строки
foreach(var line in lines) {
    Console.WriteLine(line.Index + " " + line.Text);
}

// пропустить две первые строки и обработать две следующие
foreach(var line in lines.Skip(2).Take(2)) {
    Console.WriteLine(line.Index + " " + line.Text);
}
```

File.ReadLines не загружает файлы целиком в память.
Это позволяет обрабатывать файлы с миллионами строк.